# Как в wp связать посты для выбора в админке

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте есть пост (скажем с фильмом и информацией) и кастомный пост (с актерами)... необходимо добавить на страницу фильма играющих в этом фильме актеров. Каким образом связать посты и выбирать при добавлении фильма актеров!
скрин того, что должно получиться на сайте - http://prntscr.com/n2urbl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этого можно добиться плагином "произвольные поля", допустим в типе поста фильмы создаем новое поле, "актеры", указываем то что это будет ссылкой на запись и в качестве записи указываем актеры, настройка на этом закончена.
Далее необходимо зайти в сам пост фильмы и выбрать в новом поле нужных вам актеров